# How can I account for different sampling effort in my GLMM Poisson regression using glmer() - easily reproduced example inc

Tags: mixed-model, count-data, lme4-nlme, poisson-regression, offset

I've been grappling with my dataset for what seems like a very long time now. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I would like to know how to account for the differing sampling effort in my GLMM Poisson regression using `glmer()`.

We collected count data from our plots sometimes for 3 nights, sometimes for 2 nights.

I'm not sure whether I should:

1. Create mean abundance per plot, round the means (integers for Poisson), then run my models - this removes overdispersion found in my full dataset;
2. Add an offset of sampling effort (binary 2 or 3) to the full dataset - offset(log(Sampling_effort)) - overdispersed
3. Use zero inflated neg binomial/poisson, gaussian or gamma (log) distribution
4. Switch package to glmmADMB or glmmPQL;
5. All or some of the above

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a full dataset with species richness, diversity, and specific abundances as well to examine but that just involves replicating the models, more or less.

Example below. Just run the code.

```r
# obtain data

dl_from_dropbox <- function(x, key) {
  require(RCurl)
  bin <- getBinaryURL(paste0("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/", key, "/", x),
                      ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
  con <- file(x, open = "wb")
  writeBin(bin, con)
  close(con)
  message(noquote(paste(x, "read into", getwd())))                        
}

dl_from_dropbox("Reproducible_example.csv", "4z97tlkfedmutqr")
shell.exec("Reproducible_example.csv")

# read data

data <- read.csv("Reproducible_example.csv")

# run models

library(lme4)

glmer_offset_no_date <- glmer(Total_abundance ~ Habitat + 
    (1|Loc/Plot) + offset(log(Sampling_effort)), data = data, 
    family = poisson(link = "log"))

glmer_no_offset_no_date <- glmer(Total_abundance ~ Habitat + 
    (1|Loc/Plot) , data = data, family = poisson(link = "log"))

glmer_offset_date <- glmer(Total_abundance ~ Habitat + (1|Loc/Plot) +
     (1|Date) + offset(log(Sampling_effort)), data = data, 
     family = poisson(link = "log"))

glmer_no_offset_date <- glmer(Total_abundance ~ Habitat + 
    (1|Loc/Plot) + (1|Date), data = data, 
    family = poisson(link = "log"))

AIC(glmer_no_offset, glmer_offset, glmer_no_offset_date, 
    glmer_offset_date)

# or take mean abundance per plot and run the model with/without an offset #

# tidy data
library(plyr)
Mean_abundance_per_plot <- ddply(data, c("Plot", "Loc", "Habitat", 
    "latitude", "longitude"), colwise(mean))
Mean_abundance_per_plot <- Mean_abundance_per_plot[,-6]
library(dplyr)
Mean_abundance_per_plot_rounded <- Mean_abundance_per_plot %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(round(.,0)), -c(Loc, Plot, Habitat,latitude, 
    longitude)) 

# run models 

glmer_avg_offset <- glmer(Total_abundance ~ Habitat + (1|Loc/Plot) + 
    offset(log(Sampling_effort)), 
    data = Mean_abundance_per_plot_rounded, 
    family = poisson(link = "log"))

glmer_avg_no_offset <- glmer(Total_abundance ~ Habitat + 
    (1|Loc/Plot), data = Mean_abundance_per_plot_rounded, 
    family = poisson(link = "log")) # fails to converge

# view results

AICvalues <-AIC(glmer_avg_offset, glmer_avg_no_offset, 
    glmer_no_offset_date, glmer_offset_date, glmer_no_offset_no_date, 
    glmer_offset_no_date) 
AICvalues

library(sjPlot)

sjt.glmer(glmer_avg_offset, glmer_avg_no_offset, glmer_no_offset_date, 
     glmer_offset_date, glmer_no_offset_no_date, glmer_offset_no_date, 
     depvar.labels = c("glmer_avg_offset", "glmer_avg_no_offset", 
     "glmer_no_offset_date","glmer_offset_date", 
     "glmer_no_offset_no_date", "glmer_offset_no_date"))
```

Comment: I've seen this done where fixed effects are used to account for the effort variable.  Will provide link to paper in a few min.